# when I click this product it does not do anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to show products if it's available ok added to cart else it show me an alert. if the main window is opened **without use AJAX** it's works fine but when I **
** for Sorting Item when I use sortby(AJAX) if the item available ok it works add to cart link but if the product is not available when I click it stuck which not do anything, I think the problem with the onClick="*****" but I can't solve it.
I tried many times but I can't solve it.

Thanks for help this is my code.

```
if (isset($q) || isset($p)) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat='3'".$q.$p;
    $output = '';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output .= '<img src="'.get_image($row['pro_image']).'">';

        if ($row['product_status']=='1') {                          
            $output .= '<a href="cart.php?add='.$row['pro_id'].'"><span>Add to Cart</span></a>';
        } else { 
            $output .= '<a onclick="return alert("Out of stock!")"><span>Add to Carth</span></a>';                                                
        }                 
     } // end while
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: That's the generated markup: `<a onclick="return alert("Out of stock!")">` - check the quotes.

Comment: You'll need to escape the double quotes in the else case, so like this  \"Out of stock!\"

Comment: @Andreas I check it but I don't know how to solve!...

Comment: @user6854465 I test it but it's not work.

Comment: You need to replace `onclick="return alert("Out of stock!")"` with `onclick="alert(\"Out of stock!\")"`

Comment: @Jack it's also not work.

Comment: Are you getting error messages? If you press F12 (chrome) can you look at the element and make sure it looks right?

Comment: @Jack when I press f12 it has this red error:              Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: It should give a reference. Where to? Can you give the entire error message?

Comment: @Jack I mentioned below please see it.

Comment: Could you try replacing `onclick="return alert("Out of stock!")"` with `onclick="alert(\'Out of stock!\')"`

Comment: @Jack yes I do it but it's not wotk....

Comment: Press F12, then Ctrl + Shift + C and click the `Add to Carth` button. In the inspector, right-click the element that was selected. Click Copy > Copy OuterHTML and paste it in here. Then we can tell where the issue with the quotes is.

Comment: @Jack many Thanks for You!... now It works perfect. Thanks again. I appropriate your help.    This is the solution which you say onclick="alert(\'Out of stock!\')"

Comment: Great, glad you found a solution